# Calculating $\int_0^1 2x \sin⁡(1/x^2 )-2/x \cos⁡(1/x^2 ) dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

> Calcule the improper integral $$\int_0^1 2x \sin \left( \frac 1 {x^2} \right)-\frac 2 x  \cdot\cos⁡\left(\frac 1 {x^2} \right) \mathrm{d}x.$$

It is pretty easy to see that the integral convreges, using Taylor polynomials, for example. As for calculating it, it's actually not that difficult to "guess" an antiderivative (in all $[0,1]$), say, $F(x)=x^2 \sin(1/x^2)$ for $x\neq 0$, and $F(0)=0$. However, I'm searching for a more straightforward approach, with no "good guessing" required.

Comment: The fact that you were able to "guess" an antiderivative of this form by realising that $F'(x)$ is your integrand via the product rule suggests that the right way to do it directly (without "guessing") is to use integration by parts on one of the terms (IBP follows from the product rule) -- the other term will then cancel out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int_0^1 2x \sin \left( \frac 1 {x^2} \right)-\frac 2 x  \,\cos⁡\left(\frac 1 {x^2} \right) \,dx$$

$$x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \quad \implies \quad I=\int_1^\infty \left(\frac{\sin (t)}{t^2}-\frac{\cos (t)}{t}\right)\,dt$$

$$\int \left(\frac{\sin (t)}{t^2}-\frac{\cos (t)}{t}\right)\,dt=\Big(\text{Ci}(t)-\frac{\sin (t)}{t}\Big)-\text{Ci}(t)=-\frac{\sin (t)}{t}$$